# SOLR : Matching a string with space

Tags: solr

I am trying to match a string FAIR WEATHER LANDSDOWN(query) to FAIRWEATHER STREET LANDSDOWN(index).

My schema definition as follows:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([,]+)" replacement=" " replace="all"/>      
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([,]+)" replacement=" " replace="all"/>      
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Is it possible to obtain a match using SOLR?

I had a look at WordDelimiterFilterFactory with the option catenateWords=1, but that just results in FAIRWEATHERLANDSDOWN and doesn't give me a match.

Comment: What's your rule for excluding STREET in this case? You might want to look at a shinglefilter combined with a whitespace tokenizer.

Comment: The query part is from user input... sometimes they don't include the street type when searching for addresses (single line text input for address search).

Comment: In that case you might want to use a edismax query with a minimum match-clause (i.e. allow one missing term) and a phrase boost to make sure those that have the tokens in the same sequence gets boosted to the top, together with a shinglefilter probably?

Comment: You might need a combination of approaches (e.g. edismax for query parser, synonyms, different fields types, and what-not) to get this kind of search working. It is possible, though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I ended up with an extra piece of logic in my code. I generate a list of possible names by removing spaces so a list of names might look like
FAIR WEATHER LANDSDOWN, FAIRWEATHER LANDSDOWN, FAIR WEATHERLANDSDOWN, FAIRWEATHERLANDSDOWN etc. In this way, I don't have to worry about the space. Edismax query helps in the exact search.